Proper way to get reference of something that's just been pushed to a Vec
So I need a reference to something that's just been pushed to a Vec, e.g.
my_vec.push(foo);
Somelib::do_something_with(&my_vec, &foo); // borrow checker says hi

Now, this works:
Somelib::do_something_with(&my_vec, &my_vec.last().unwrap());

But is that the way? Or what's the proper way to do it?

Please show a complete example, because as written both code snippets look fine. Including the actual compiler output would also be helpful.

Personally, I do the second, with a // Safe to unwrap comment

@vallentin Instead of using unwrap() with a comment, consider using expect() with an appropriate message.

When you're pushing an element onto a Vec by value, you're moving that value. This invalidates any existing references to that value. The borrow checker is correct.
If you need the value to be moved into the Vec, you have no choice but to get a reference to the item from the Vec in some fashion. Otherwise, keep a Vec of references instead of a Vec of values, and the problem goes away.
If you need to do this in more than one place, I'd suggest implementing an extension trait for this. This way, the logic lives in only one place, and you don't have to put .unwrap() or .expect() in as many places.
For example:
pub trait VecExt<T> {
    fn push_returning_ref(&mut self, item: T) -> &T;
}

impl<T> VecExt<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn push_returning_ref(&mut self, item: T) -> &T {
        self.push(item);
        self.last().expect("vec must have item after push")
    }
}

fn example_usage() {
    let item: String = String::from("hello");
    let mut list: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let ref_to_item: &str = list.push_returning_ref(item);
}


I would suggest returning -> &mut T with .last_mut() since it doesn't change anything about mutably borrowing the Vec (because .push() is involved) as long as the returned reference exists. It gives, however, the opportunity to mutate through the returned reference if needed. And of course, &mut T implicitly decays to &T when no mutation is needed.

Note this won't actually help OP because ref_to_item will mutably borrow list (since push_returning_ref takes it by mutable reference). OP's original workaround code is probably as good as they'll be able to do in this situation.
